# Scope PHP variable not persisting

Tags: php

I am declaring a php variable in my php block.However when i try to echo the variable in another php block it isn't printing the value. What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
 <?php 
 $data = $content->parameters;
 $name=$data['name'];
 //Code below is working
 echo $name;
 ?>

 //JQuery and HTML code

 <?php
  //Code below is not working
 echo $name;
 ?>
```

Comment: Is it in the same file?

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo at all in the actual code?

Comment: Try to see the html source of the page

Comment: Have you enabled `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`?

Comment: Did you close your jQuery and HTML code correctly?

Comment: Is the JQuery and HTML code called in a separate request? I hate to advise you that PHP doesn't persist variables between requests

Comment: its in the same request. I don't think the problem is with the closing of the HTML code since I tried to create a dummy PHP block right after this one and print the variable with no change in result.